# File conversion in adf

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to convert binary file to readable format like any file type like CSV or text.

I have a binary files in my blob storage and this files move from input to output in readable format

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Some debugging information would be useful

Comment: What is the error you facing? Provide those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Azure Data Factory doesn't natively support the conversation you need, you can use Azure Function to transform files from one format to another, but you must write code for the transformation.
Azure Data Factory can call an Azure Function for each file and indicate where to place the result.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity